# Google map object undefined inside Vuejs created method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

```
created () {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      console.log(this.position = position.coords)
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()  //ERROR IN THIS LINE 
      var googleLatLon = { lat: position.croods.latitude, lng: position.croods.longitude }
      geocoder.geocode({ 'location': googleLatLon }, (results, error) => {
        console.log(results[0].address_components[2].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[3].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[4].long_name + ', ' + results[0].address_components[5].long_name)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<link rel="manifest" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.publicPath %>static/manifest.json">
```

I have included the google's map api in index.html and the above code is from App.vue. Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: what is the exact error you find?

Comment: Basically i want address from the above code, it is fetching the latitude and longitude, but i don't know how to get address from that. Well i used the regular method, for that it is showing google.maps.Geocoder() is not defined

Comment: does the console log show you anything?

Comment: Yea it only prints first console content, it skips the second

Comment: Post your index.html code, are you sure you are including google maps script before the bundle script?

Comment: Yeah, like what @yuriy636 said. Also, you might want to try `mounted` instead of `created`

Comment: I did, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are writing wrong variable name in 
`position.croods`. 
it should be `position.coords` .
There is no error in

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess i need to install it via npm. Structure varies I guess